# How to hide ip address and port when accessing digital ocean droplet

Tags: django, dns, digital-ocean, google-domain-api

I have a django app deployed to 0.0.0.0:8000 on a digital ocean droplet.  I also have a domain name off of google domains.  Google domain simply redirects to the digital ocean nameservers:

```
ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
ns3.digitalocean.com
```

My digital ocean domain has one A record:

```
@ ip.address
```

This lets me access my django webapp by:

```
 http://domainName:8000
```

Is there a way I can configure this not to include the port number?  Something like:

```
 http://domainName
```

Comment: You can configure Apache or nginx reverse proxy om the same droplet. If you decide to go that  (very simple yet robust and flexible) way, you should probably try to do it yourself and then come with specific question if you encounter any issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, http default port is 80 and https default port is 443

you can try:

1. Change your listening to 0.0.0.0:80

> you can access your django webapp by: http://domainName

2. Change your listening to 0.0.0.0:443 with ssl key、cert

> you can access your django webapp by: https://domainName

```
maybe you needed to gen a ssl cert
```

Also you can use NAT:

samples

```
iptables -i device -t nat -A PREROUTING -p  tcp -d publicIP  --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination listeningIP:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you just run Django server and you made dns record point to your ip.
This is not the way to deploy your django app.
You should have NGINX or Apache as a web server and use uWSGI as application server and Django after that.

The web server is responsible for redirecting http requests to the right port, in your case to default 80 port, not 8000 that uses Django.

You can read some of the Digital Ocean tutorials:[How To Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)